# Rails 4 scoping with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following class:

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :drinks, -> { where(item.submenu: Submenu.last) }
end
```

As you can see, I want to get all the order items where the order item isn't in some submenu (in this case in the last Submenu for example). But this code doesn't work. The errors:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':' scope :drinks, -> { where(item.submenu: Submenu.last) }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't use symbols with dot inside like this (`item.submenu:`), that's why it throws `SyntaxError`. To make it work, you could join your association and query it with:

```
scope :drinks, -> { joins(:item).where(items: {submenu_id: Submenu.last}) }
```

Comment: @malcoauri could you be more specific?

Comment: @malcoauri what's the problem then?

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: items.submenu: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "order_items" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."id" = "order_items"."item_id" WHERE "items"."submenu" = 1

Comment: @malcoauri check out edited answer. I changed `submenu` to `submenu_id`.